# how to create persian content in pdf using eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, pdf, itext

I have a problem with inserting UNICODE characters in a PDF file in eclipse.
There is some solution for this that it is not very efficient for me.

The solution is like this.

```
document.add(new Paragraph("Unicode: \u0418", new Font(bfComic, 12)));
```

I want to retrieve data from a database and show them to the user and my characters are in Arabic script and sometimes in Farsi script.

What solution do you suggest?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are experiencing different problems:

**Encoding of the data:**

Please [download chapter 2 of my book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAqgF.png) and go to section 2.2.2 entitled "The Phrase object: a List of Chunks with leading". In this section, look for the title "Database encoding versus the default CharSet used by the JVM".

You will see that database values are retrieved like this:

```
String name1 = new String(rs.getBytes("given_name"), "UTF-8");
```

That’s because the database contains different names with special characters. You risk that these special characters are displayed as gibberish if you would retrieve the field like this:

```
String name2 = rs.getString("given_name")
```

**Encoding of the font:**

You create your font like this:

```
Font font = new Font(bfComic, 12);
```

You don't show how you create `bfComic`, but I assume that this object is a `BaseFont` object using `IDENTITY_H` as encoding.

**Writing from right to left / making ligatures**

Although your code will work to show a single character, it won't work to show a sentence correctly.

Suppose that `name1` is the Arabic version of the name "Lawrence of Arabia" and that we want to write this name to a PDF. This is done three times in the following screen shot:

[image]

The first line is wrong, because the characters are in the wrong order. They are written from left to right whereas they should be written from right to left. This is what will happen when you do:

```
document.add(name1);
```

Even if the encoding is correct, you're rendering the text incorrectly.

The second line is also wrong. The characters are now in the correct order, but no ligatures are made: ل followed by و should be combined into a single glyph: لو

You can only achieve this by adding the content to a `ColumnText` or `PdfPCell` object, and by setting the run direction to `PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL`. For instance:

```
pdfCell.setRunDirection(PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL);
```

Now the text will be rendered correctly.

This is explained in chapter 11 of my book. You can find a full example here: [Ligatures2](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=210)

Comment: *but I assume that this object is a BaseFont object using IDENTITY_H as encoding.* - you are an optimist. ;)

Comment: @Bruno Lowagie: i have created pdf in english text but when i use createfont class an error occur that say that font.ttf can not be embedded due to licensing restrictions.how can i solve this error?

Comment: Use another font or get a license to embed the font. You should always respect licenses. For instance: if you use iText in a closed source project, you should either open source your code under the same open source license as iText, or purchase a commercial license for your use of iText.

Comment: That's what I meant. Happy to hear you've solved the problem.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I would like to knowo your thoughts on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55439445/updating-text-of-a-pdf-cannot-replace-string-with-arabic-word-itext-java .. Can you please have a look at this one?\