# iText 5.5.3 PDFPCell : long text doesn't fit corrctly in cell (wrap text incorrectly)

Tags: java, pdf, itext

i am trying to create a Persian PDF containing tables and i want to write in it. when my string is long it doesn't fit the cell correctly. feels like String fills the cell upside down!... i mean for example when i want to write  "hello my friend . what's up?"
in the cell the output is like this:

---

| what's up?   |

| my friend    |

| hello        |

---

but of course in Persian (it's Ok in English)

here i attached the code by the way

```
        private  LanguageProcessor al = new ArabicLigaturizer();
        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(al.process(persian_text), fontNormal));
        cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
        cell.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_TOP);
        cell.setBorderWidth(0);
        table.addCell(cell);
```

i would be thankful with your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First this: iText 5.5.5 doesn't exist (yet). You are probably using another version.

As for your problem: you are using the wrong approach. The correct approach is explained in the answer to "[how to create persian content in pdf using eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26818555/how-to-create-persian-content-in-pdf-using-eclipse)."

```
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(arabic_text, fontNormal));
cell.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_TOP);
cell.setBorderWidth(0);
cell.setRunDirection(PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL);
table.addCell(cell);
```

You should not use `ArabicLigaturizer` directly! In the above code snippet, `arabic_text` is the original `String` with the Arabic characters. Note that you should not use Unicode characters in your source code. See the second observation in my answer to this question: [Can't get Czech characters while generating a PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26631815/cant-get-czech-characters-while-generating-a-pdf)