# How do make unicode to print from method return type in java

Tags: java, string, methods, unicode, itext

[image]I am using statement below to print unicode as a string in java

```
System.out.println("\u0917\u094d\u0930\u093e\u0939\u0915");
```

It prints  ग्राहक  on  console.
Now instead of passing simple string inside println() I am using like this

```
System.out.println(this.HindiConvertUni("ग्राहक"));
public  String HindiConvertUni(String str)
{
    StringBuffer ostr = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)        
    {
        char ch = str.charAt(i);
        if ((ch >= 0x0020) && (ch <= 0x007e)) // Does the char need to be converted to unicode?
        {
          ostr.append(ch);    // No.
        } else // Yes.
        {
            ostr.append("\\u");    // standard unicode format.
            // Get hex value of the char.
            String hex = Integer.toHexString(str.charAt(i) & 0xFFFF); 
            // Prepend zeros because unicode requires 4 digits
            for (int j = 0; j < 4 - hex.length(); j++) 
            {
                ostr.append("0");
            }
            // standard unicode format. 
            ostr.append(hex.toLowerCase());    
        }
    }
    return (new String(ostr)); 
}
```

Now i want to print mine string which i am using as argument. But it print like \u0917\u094d\u0930\u093e\u0939\u0915
i am looking to print it as ग्राहक instead of unicode.
How do make it possible.Thanx in advanced.
Actually i am using iText to make report i am doing

```
                BaseFont unicode = BaseFont.createFont("/home/mani/current/ARIALUNI.TTF", 
                BaseFont.IDENTITY_H,    true);
                Font font=new Font(unicode,12,Font.NORMAL,new BaseColor(50,205,50));                  
                PdfPCell customerLblCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("\u0917\u094d\u0930\u093e\u0939\u0915",
                font));
```

However i am looking something similar to

```
                     PdfPCell customerLblCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(this.HindiConvertUni("ग्राहक"),
                font));
```

But it prints unicode instead of ग्राहक!

I am trying to print like that ऐसा करने की कोशिश but it idid like in picture above.

Comment: Please put more effort into formatting your code in future posts - I've fixed this one up, but it was *really* hard to read to start with. Now, as to your question - yes, you're explicitly escaping the string, so I'm not surprised it was escaped. If you didn't want to escape it, what *did* you want to do? Why not just use `System.out.println("ग्राहक");`? It feels like you need to understand the difference between the actual text (which is just a sequence of UTF-16 code units) and a possible *source code* representation of that text, which can include escape sequences.

Comment: thnx buddy! i will try iam pretty new here. @jon Skeet

Comment: I am using Itext library inorder to print reports. But as itext didn;t recognise hindi text(ग्राहक) . First i am converting string to unicode and from these unicode itext does the desired report.But problem is as mentioned above

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "converting string to Unicode" when all strings *are* Unicode to start with. If you mean "escaping Unicode characters with `\u`" then that's fine. But if it works with itext and that's what you're trying to achieve, what's the problem? Please edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: I am trying to make reports (in pdf) in all languages but iText didn't understand indic glyphs. So first of all i am trying to convert hindi strings into unicode and then make it possible to understand by iText by rendering fonts as i mentioned above.

Comment: Why you can't use `new Phrase("ग्राहक", font)`? If you have the string already in UTF format, why you want to convert it as escaped unicode characters?

Comment: @SubOptimal iText didn't understand like that

Comment: @manikantgautam And that way it's working `new Phrase("\u0917\u094d\u0930\u093e\u0939\u0915", font)`?

Comment: @SubOptimal Phrase("\u0917\u094d\u0930\u093e\u0939\u0915", font) is working fine

Comment: So did it work or not in iText? You said before that it did: "itext does the desired report" - but then you're claiming that you still had problems. It's really unclear. (And again, please edit your question to sort out the code indentation. Look at the preview before you submit, and make sure it looks as readable as possible.)

Comment: @manikantgautam: If it works that way when escaped *in source code* then it should be fine using the non-escaped form too, so long as you've configured your compiler to use the right encoding (to understand how you're representing the source code itself). That has nothing to do with iText.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I belive you have a misunderstanding of escaped unicode characters in Java code.

```
String s = "ग्राहक";
String t = "\u0917\u094d\u0930\u093e\u0939\u0915";
System.out.println("s = " + s);
System.out.println("t = " + t);
System.out.println("s equals t: " + s.equals(t));
```

output

```
s = ग्राहक
t = ग्राहक
s equals t: true
```

As you can see both strings are equal. So `new Phrase("ग्राहक", font)` and `new Phrase("\u0917\u094d\u0930\u093e\u0939\u0915", font)` result in the same code. Either both are working or both are not working.

Reason is that an escaped unicode character like `"\u0917"` will be substitude at **compile time** by the compiler to the unicode character itself `"ग्"`.

On the other side your method `HindiConvertUni("ग्राहक")` generates at **runtime** a string `"\u0917\u094d\u0930\u093e\u0939\u0915"` which is not automatically converted into the corresponding unicode characters.

Amending the above snippet

```
String x = HindiConvertUni("ग्राहक");
System.out.println("x = " + x);
System.out.println("x equals t: " + x.equals(t));
```

the output is

```
s = ग्राहक
t = ग्राहक
s equals t: true
x = \u0917\u094d\u0930\u093e\u0939\u0915
x equals t: false
```

Maybe this makes the difference clear.

**added after OP comment**
As far I could figure out during searching the internet the problem seems to be related to following facts (everything AFAIK as I don't read/speak hindi). Hindi is written from left to right, but here are exceptions, like in your case with the vowel 'I' (unicode \u093F). When in the character encoding it's on the right of a consonant, then 'I' is rendered to the left of that consonant. Both characters are rendered on the same vertical position.

For demonstration.

```
System.out.println("current  : \u0936 - \u0936\u093F");
System.out.println("expected : \u0936\u093F - \u0936");
System.out.println("separated: \u0936 - \u093F - \u0936");
```

output

```
current  : श - शि
expected : शि - श
separated: श - ि - श
```

Following some ideas what might be the reason in your case.

- the order of the unicode characters is wrong and you really get them from the database as "\u0936\u0936\u093F" instead of "\u0936\u093F\u0936"
- you don't use the latest `iText` version (see the [comment and linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27485753/itext-5-5-3-pdfpcell-long-text-doesnt-fit-corrctly-in-cell-wrap-text-incorre) ones from [Bruo Lowagie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1622493/bruno-lowagie))
- or maybe iText isn't able to handle this specific case, couldn't fully prove it based on this [test code](https://github.com/itext/itextg/blob/master/src/test/java/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/IndicLigatures.java) (if this should be the case, have a look in the [source](https://github.com/itext/itextg/blob/master/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/languages/DevanagariLigaturizer.java) , fix it and send a pull request)

Comment: Thanx @SubOptimal! Somehow i am managed to prints it inside report.But again the problem is , i am not getting desired output.As i am trying to print ऐसा करने की कोशिश but it prints something different as you can see from image above.

Comment: @manikantgautam Could you please explain in your original question what is not as you expect. The sentence `ऐसा करने की कोशिश` I can see in the screenshot.

Comment: as u can see i am fetching record from DB(mysql) in this formate  ऐसा करने की कोशिश but is not printing as it is inside pdf document above i had mentioned in image.It prints कोशशि instead of कोशिश

Comment: yes sir !!! i saw in morning it is quite helpful, i am thank full to you.I will let you know whether it is working me or not for all strings.