# How to display Arabic in PDF created using iText

Tags: java, pdf, itext, arabic

I need your help in display the Arabic content and to start the writing from right to left in the PDF sample that I am trying to create. Here is the sample code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try {

        BaseFont ArialBase = BaseFont.createFont("C:\\Users\\dell\\Desktop\\arialbd.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, true);
        Font ArialFont = new Font(ArialBase, 20);


        Document document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);


        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\dell\\Desktop\\HelloWorld.pdf"));
        document.setMargins(72f, 72f, 72f, 0f);

        document.open();
        document.add(new Paragraph("الموقع الإلكتروني,",ArialFont));
        document.close();
        System.out.println("PDF Completed");

    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

With the above code, the Arabic text will be shown as below:

Ø§Ù„Ù…ÙˆÙ‚Ø¹ Ø§Ù„Ø¥Ù„ÙƒØªØ±ÙˆÙ†ÙŠ,

which is unidentified and the text is from left to right. So how can I solve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Wrong encoding:**

It is a bad programming practice to use non-ASCII characters in your source code. For instance, you have `"الموقع الإلكتروني"`. This `String` should be interpreted as double byte UNICODE characters. However, when you *save* the source code file using an encoding different from UNICODE, or when you *compile* that code using a different encoding, or when *your JVM* uses a different encoding each double-byte character risks to be corrupted, resulting in gibberish such as `"Ø§Ù„Ù…ÙˆÙ‚Ø¹ Ø§Ù„Ø¥Ù„ÙƒØªØ±ÙˆÙ†ÙŠ"`

How to solve this? Use the UNICODE notation: `"\u0627\u0644\u0645\u0648\u0642\u0639 \u0627\u0644\u0625\u0644\u0643\u062a\u0631\u0648\u0646\u064a"`

Please consult the official documentation, the free ebook [The Best iText Questions on StackOverflow](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-stackoverflow-questions.html), where you will discover that this problem has already been described here: [Can't get Czech characters while generating a PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26631815/cant-get-czech-characters-while-generating-a-pdf)

**Wrong font:**

If you read this book carefully, you'll discover that your example might not work because you may be using the wrong font. This is explained in my answer to this question: [Arabic characters from html content to pdf using iText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30214147/arabic-characters-from-html-content-to-pdf-using-itext)

You are assuming that `arialbd.ttf` can produce Arabic glyphs. As far as I know only `arialuni.ttf` supports Arabic.

**Wrong approach:**

Furthermore, you are overlooking the fact that you can only use Arabic in the context of the `ColumnText` and the `PdfPCell` object. This is explained here: [how to create persian content in pdf using eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26818555/how-to-create-persian-content-in-pdf-using-eclipse)

For instance:

```
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(
    "c:/windows/fonts/arialuni.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
Font font = new Font(bf, 20);
ColumnText column = new ColumnText(writer.getDirectContent());
column.setSimpleColumn(36, 730, 569, 36);
column.setRunDirection(PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL);
column.addElement(new Paragraph(
    "\u0627\u0644\u0645\u0648\u0642\u0639 \u0627\u0644\u0625\u0644\u0643\u062a\u0631\u0648\u0646\u064a", font));
column.go();
```

Note that I am using the `Identity-H` encoding because UNICODE is involved.

Comment: I think you have answered this special question 1000 times or more. right? If a lot of people are asking the same question, something is wrong. make the Unicode, default. It's much more easier than answering this question every day.

Comment: I can't make the UNICODE default. That's up to the OS that saves files, compilers that compile the code, JVMs that execute the bytecode. There are also implications in PDF: the uncompressed content stream of text when using composite fonts (e.g. when `/Identity-H` is used) takes double the space that is needed when using a simple font. I wouldn't have to answer this question every day if only developers weren't too stubborn to read [the documentation](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ebook-stackoverflow-questions.html). That's why there's an F in RTFM.

Comment: Thanks for the help and I understood the issue now

Comment: what about iText 7 ? the above mentioned lines do not work

Comment: @MohammedNafie Please read [chapter 1](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-1-introducing-pdffont-class) of the "iText 7: Building Blocks" tutorial and you'll learn that iText 7 requires the closed source add-on [pdfCalligraph](http://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdfcalligraph) to render Arabic.

Answer (score 2):

go with PdfTable will print arabic text in pdf. following is the code

```
Font f = FontFactory.getFont("assets/NotoNaskhArabic-Regular.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
    f.setStyle(Font.BOLD);
    f.setColor(new BaseColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary)));
   PdfPTable pdfTable=new PdfPTable(1);
   pdfTable.setRunDirection(PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL);
   PdfPCell pdfPCell=new PdfPCell();
   pdfPCell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
   Paragraph paragraph=new Paragraph(string,f);
   paragraph.setAlignment(PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT);
   pdfPCell.addElement(paragraph);
   pdfTable.addCell(pdfPCell);
   document.add(pdfTable);
```

this code will add arabic text in your pdf. `pdfPCell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);` will give paragraph view for PdfTable
[image: check output of above code]